# PowerShell: How can I write folder names found in a directory to an array but exclude specific folders

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script that needs to write the names of all folders found in a subdirectory to an array.  However, I need to exclude specific folders.

For example, I would like to write all folder names found in `C:\myFolder\MySubfolder` with the exception of the `C:\myFolder\mySubFolder\PendingClaims` folder.

This is what I have so far.

```
$myMonthFoldersArray = Get-ChildItem $myPathToYearFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.fullName -notmatch 'Pending'}
```

Comment: ... and what's wrong with the code you have? Is it not working as expected?

Comment: When I put Write-Host  $myMonthFoldersArray[$myMonthFoldersArrayIndex]  in a loop, to view the array, I get "True, True, True, False" instead of a list of all the folder names.

Answer (score 0):

this should works :

`$myMonthFoldersArray = Get-ChildItem $myPathToYearFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.Name -notmatch "Pending"}`